# phpUnit failing with weird error

Tags: php, phpunit

```
PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/Test.php on line 66
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:78
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
PHP   9. include_once() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95
PHP  10. phpunit_autoload() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php:0
PHP  11. require() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php:203
PHP  12. phpunit_autoload() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php:0
```

The line in question has:

`public function run(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result = NULL)`

When I remove the `= NULL` it goes through but fails on another line that also has an `= NULL`, the screwed up thing is that the error basically says it HAS to be NULL, which it IS.

I have not modified PhpUnit in any way, I installed it using the method described here:

http://www.giocc.com/installing-phpunit-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal.html

I honestly don't understand why this is happening.. something tells me PHP is bugged in that it's giving me the wrong error.

Comment: Did you recently update your PHP? What version and O/S are you running? I agree it looks like PHP is broken. Those lines are fine.

Comment: I don't think PHP was updated recently, the only change made was that I updated from PhpUnit 3.6.3 to the latest. I have PHP version 5.3.6 on Ubuntu 11.10/.

Comment: After you remove the default, when it fails on the subsequent NULL, what is the error message in that case?

Comment: I can't find the tweet from Sebastian, but I recall some major bugs in the latest PHPUnit with PHP 5.3.x. I'd found a few bugs similar to what you are seeing, but in different areas. Can you use a debugger and step through the PHPUnit code and post those results?

Comment: @Spudley: it gives the exact same error for a different class, which also has the = NULL statement.

Comment: @EricCope I found nothing out of the ordinary while debugging. Here's the last breakpoint I could get before it crashed and burned: http://i.imgur.com/69BvY.png .

Comment: Okey.. I managed to work around it by changing all the `NULL` values to `null`, yes the EXACT SAME VALUE - but in lowercase.. I have no idea why this works. Also I had to disable xdebug as it was still crashing with error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function filter() on a non-object in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php on line 608`. I think both PHPUnit and PHP 5.3 have some SERIOUS bugs..

Comment: Try updating PHPUnit as 3.6.3 is pretty old for the 3.6.x branch.

Comment: phpunit 3.6.3 is _quite_ old so I don't remember any issues that version might have had. 5.3.6 has some issues and is also outdated but I've had that combiniation running for quite some time and never seen your issue. Fun stuff :)

Comment: That PHP is treating `NULL` and `null` differently points to a severe problem with your PHP installation.

Comment: Oh damn I found the problem, and it's a silly one on my side. I had a constant file that was defining NULL for use in an ORM library. It's defined in it's own namespace so it shouldn't have interfered with the global constant, but I guess constants are a bit tricky with namespaces..

Comment: The only reference to namespaces on the [`define()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#90282) docs page is a comment that implies that the function is not namespace-aware.

Comment: You're right, I had wrongly assumed it was. Thank you.

Comment: @Naatan: for people looking for this... I would say: post the answer to your question below. Saves time if people looking for answers don't have to scroll through the comments, people looking for unanswered questions not to have this question come up, and it's perfectly legal to answer your own question ;)

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, I have provided the answer below and will mark it as such once the timer has worn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, quoting myself from the comments section:

> Oh damn I found the problem, and it's a silly one on my side. I had a constant file that was defining NULL for use in an ORM library. It's defined in it's own namespace so it shouldn't have interfered with the global constant, but I guess constants are a bit tricky with namespaces..

So TIL, if you want to define constants in a namespace, simply adding namespace to the top of the file won't suffice, you have to define the constants like so

```php
define('NAMESPACE\CONSTANT',        'value');
// or
define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\CONSTANT', 'value'); // to use the current namespace
```